# Troubleshooting MongoDB Mongoose TTL Index Not Deleting Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, ttl

Mongodb (mongoose) does not automatically delete documents.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const pre_queue = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    expired: {
      type: Date,
      expires: 120,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    user_used: String,
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("pre_queue", pre_queue);
```

`Expired` creates an index that should delete the document with the field "expired" 120 seconds after creation.

The document is not deleted.

Could it be because my ABC field is unique?

I attempted to set up a TTL (Time-To-Live) index in my Mongoose schema to automatically delete documents after a certain period. To do this, I added the expires property to a Date field in the schema.

I expected that documents would be automatically deleted from the MongoDB collection once their TTL had expired, based on the expires property I set in the schema.

However, despite configuring the TTL index and verifying the setup, the documents did not get deleted automatically as expected. I checked the MongoDB version, the connection stability, and the server time, but the documents still didn't self-destruct according to the TTL.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue or if there's something else I should consider to make the TTL index work as intended.